# ¿Como puedo eliminar registros de una tabla en MySQL en base a otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, consola

tengo una tabla empleados y otra departamento:
[image: tablas:]

Debo eliminar en la tabla empleados a todos los empleados que hagan parte de un departamento que tenga un presupuesto mayor a 60000.
En este caso tendría que eliminar a los que hacen parte de informática e investigación.

He intentado hacer lo anterior con el siguiente código pero no se me ha dado lo que necesito:

`delete empleados from empleados inner join departamento on empleados.departamento =
departamento.coDepartamento where departamento.presupuesto_USD > 60000;`

Según la consola no hay errores en el query pero tampoco elimina ningún empleado.

Que puedo hacer?

Ayuda, ¡por favor!

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario que hagas nada. Si te fijas en los datos, los únicos departamentos con más de 60kUSD de presupuesto son el 14 y el 77, y ningún empleado pertenece a esos departamentos. De ahí que:

- La consulta no dé ningún mensaje de error y
- No elimine ningún registro

Quédate tranquilo que está todo bien.

También tendrías la opción de plantear una consulta más sencilla, del tipo:

```
DELETE FROM empleados
  WHERE departamento IN (
    SELECT coDepartamento FROM departamento
      WHERE presupuesto_USD > 60000
  );
```

Aunque, que sepas usar el `DELETE` con un `JOIN`, te puede venir bien para casos en los que realmente se necesite, como el borrado de datos en cascada con una única consulta.  Por ejemplo, si también quisieras borrar los departamentos implicados:

```
SET @@foreign_key_checks=0;
DELETE empleados,departamento
  FROM empleados
  JOIN departamento
  ON empleados.departamento =
      departamento.coDepartamento
  WHERE departamento.presupuesto_USD > 60000;
```